# What does "invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' ..."mean?

Tags: uiswitch, xcode11

Environment: Version 11.0 beta 3 (11M362v)

Here's the full text:

```
invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. 
This message will only appear once per execution.
Hello World
```

This message only appears when I click on a UISwitch button that is connected to an action; here, printing "Hello World".

Apparently the behavior of the action isn't affected.

[image]

As a comparison, I've created a UIBarButtonItem in the toolbar which behaves normally.  So there's something fishy about the switch button.

**Question:** why would this appear and what does it mean?  Remedy?

Comment: Is this using `SwiftUI`? Can you post the code? Using Xcode 11 beta 5 and SwiftUI I also get this error: `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes'` for my `Toggle` views, see SO Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57558760/1311272

Comment: I have the same issue with a switch on a real device.
**Even without any action added** - the error occurs the first time the switch is pressed.
Xcode 11.0 iOS 13.1.2 - iPhone Xs

Comment: Did anyone figure this one out?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: I am also seeing this message being printed when using a UISwitch in an iOS app written in Objective-C. The UISwitch is on a view that is defined in a storyboard. The UIViewController is being shown by a call to  presentViewController: animated: completion:

Comment: I get the same thing, and the animation is also delayed for some reason

Comment: For me, the error occurs with a `UISwitch` or a `UIStepper` if I add a target to `UIControlEventValueChanged`, but the error occurs before my target method is actually called, so it isn't related to the code in the target method. It does not occur if I don't add the target. My view controller is running inside a popover, and the popover won't close after it occurs, so it's a real problem and not just a random log message. :-(

Comment: I see it with a SwiftUI Toggle control (which wraps a UISwitch) on a real device.

Comment: Another point of data on the Toggle problem: I have my MacBook set to support Tap to Click on the trackpad (System Preferences -> Trackpad -> Tap to click). All other interactions with UI Controls in Simulator work, but tap to click doesn’t register on Toggles. I have to do a regular press (physical click) to get Toggle ui elements to register a click. So, there’s definitely something different about Toggles vs. other UI Controls. [Catalina; Xcode 11]

Comment: Occurs for me Aug 6, 2023

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think it's a warning that Apple should fix it itself. Even in [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/using_collection_view_compositional_layouts_and_diffable_data_sources) sample project which is from WWDC19 this problem exists. There is a UISwitch in a cell of a table. When I tap it, the mentioned warning is raised.

So, in my view, it is a bug that Apple should deal with.

Comment: I still receive the same warning today. When is Apple planning to fix this?

Comment: Still occurring January 18, 2022. With date and toggle within an @ObservedObject, changing date to today's date and toggling leads to a sheet disappearing in debug mode, not release.

Comment: Still exists Nov 17th, 2022. Just wanted to add to this haha

Comment: Error: Hello Everyone! It's Feb 1, 2023 and I'm still alive!

Answer (score 31):

Judging from the replies by Apple Developer Relations to [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/132035), this is a bug in UIKit and one that Apple is tracking. Until the bug is fixed, the advice is to treat this as "log noise".

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem:
When I got the call-back from the UISwitch, I reloaded the UITableView.
I think that the call-back is initiated before the UISwitch finishes changing its context, and reloading the cell in that state creates some conflict.

With that theory, I solved my problem like so:
I separated the cells into sections, where the cell with the UISwitch was in its own section. 
When I got the call-back from the UISwitch, I reloaded all the sections except the section that has the cell with the UISwitch.

Comment: Can you show an example of this in more detail, I have the same issue but don't understand your answer.  In my case I don't have a UITableView and some people are using SwiftUI or Interface Builder.  Appreciate the help if you can find a universal answer.

Comment: I use this approach - the switch reloads a different section to the one itself is located in, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I also tried separating the UISwitch into its own separate section in a UITableView (static cells), but still have the problem. For me it occurs when calling tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() in a UIKit app. A google search shows folks are having this problem with Apple's SwiftUI code, and it showed up on some Ray Wenderlich forums. I also see the problem in some of Apple's EveryoneCanCode examples. Perhaps a bug with UISwitch?

Comment: It's a known bug Apple is tracking. They claim it is harmless (relatively) and recommend treating it as "log noise." See [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/132035) on the Apple dev forums.