# SwiftUI running on Simulator/Preview: Toggle not working, console logs: "invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes'"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

## Update: This was a red herring

So my original question asked how to make a navigation link disabled and only enabled if two `Toggle` affecting two `@State var isXYZToggleOn Bool` properties are both **true**. This has always been working, my first attempt using `.disabled(!(hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions && hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy))` was the correct one (also suggested by @superpuccio, but using two negatations and one boolean or (`||`)).

Turns I did not get my `NavigationLink` to be enabled because the toggling did not work, not because of incorrect usage of the booleans and `disabled` view modifier.

Running on device, instead of simulator made everything work! But I still see the warning message as soon as I press any `Toggle` (but only once):

```
invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
```

I get this error message running on simulator too, but then the `NavigationLink` does not get enabled ever.

I'm running Xcode 5 beta on Catalina 5 beta on a 2016 Macbook Pro. Deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, restarting my computer, resetting the simulator, changing simulator, nothing helps. I still see `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes'` when I press the first `Toggle`, and the `NavigationLink` never gets enabled.

So the new question is:

#### Running on simulator: how to solve `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes'` problem causing my `@State` bound to `Toggle` to never become `true`??

## Original question

Using XCode 11 beta 5 and SwiftUI. In a `WelcomeScene` I have two `Toggle` views, one toggle for accepting Terms & Conditions and one toggle for Privacy Policy. These toggles updates two separate `@State` properties respectively.

In the bottom of the scene I have a `NagivationLink` (button) which will take to the next scene, which I would like to be ***disabled* by default** and only be *enabled* when **both** `hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions` and `hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy` states are `true`.

When initiating a `NavigationLink` there is a `isActive` argument, which takes a `Binding<Bool>`, which sounds like the correct thing. However, `@Binding` properties cannot be marked `lazy`, thus I cannot make it a computed property being dependent on `hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions` and `hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy`.

There is also a `disabled` view modifier which takes a `Bool`, which is also incorrect since it does not get updated...

```swift
struct WelcomeScene: View {

    @State var hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions: Bool = false
    @State var hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(named: "MyImage")

            Spacer()

            Text("Welcome friend!".uppercased())
                .font(.system(size: 55))

            Toggle(isOn: $hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions) {
                Text("I agree to the Terms and Conditions")
            }.toggleStyle(DefaultToggleStyle())

            Toggle(isOn: $hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy) {
                Text("I agree to the Privacy Policy")
            }.toggleStyle(DefaultToggleStyle())

            // This does not compile 'Binding<Bool> is not convertible to Bool', but I cannot figure out how to create a compupted property binding using those 2 states...
            NavigationLink("Proceed", destination: SignInScene(), isActive: ($hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions && $hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy))
        }.padding(30)
    }
}
```

How can I make a `NavigationLink` `disabled` by default and only `enabled` when both toggles are `on`?

Comment: Also, when running in iOS simulator, when pressing any toggle I get: `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56980875/1311272

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to get a publisher from a state so it was necessary to move things into an `ObservableObject`. From `@Published` items one can access it's publisher via `$hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy`, which one can use in things like `Publishers.CombineLatest` to combine two publisher values and based on that set other variables.

Two Navigation links are necessary because once one was active, making it inactive does not hide what is displayed in the details view. The second is basically there to show content while the terms are not accepted yet.

Note: What you show here is a split view (using `NavigationLink` embedded in `NavigationView`). You can also use .sheet (which gets controlled by `isActive`) or a conditional to switch between the views.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Settings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions: Bool = false
    @Published var hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy: Bool = false

    @Published var isActive = false
    @Published var isNotActive = true

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

    init() {
        self.cancellable = Publishers.CombineLatest($hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy, $hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions).map{
            return $0.0 && $0.1
        }.sink{
            self.isActive = $0
            self.isNotActive = !$0
        }
    }
}

struct WelcomeSceneView: View {
    @ObservedObject var settings = Settings()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Image(uiImage: welcomeLogo)

                Spacer()

                Text("Welcome friend!".uppercased())
                //.font(.system(size: 55))

                Toggle(isOn: $settings.hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions) {
                    Text("I agree to the Terms and Conditions")
                }.toggleStyle(DefaultToggleStyle())

                Toggle(isOn: $settings.hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy) {
                    Text("I agree to the Privacy Policy")
                }.toggleStyle(DefaultToggleStyle())


                // This does not compile 'Binding<Bool> is not convertible to Bool', but I cannot figure out how to create a compupted property binding using those 2 states...
                Text("is active: \(settings.isActive.description)")
                NavigationLink("Can proceed", destination: SignInScene(), isActive: $settings.isActive)
                .hidden()
                NavigationLink("Can not proceed", destination: PleaseConfirmView(), isActive: $settings.isNotActive)
                .hidden()
            }.padding(30)
        }
    }

    let welcomeLogo = UIImage(systemName: "headphones")!
}

struct SignInScene: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Some sign in scene")
    }
}

struct PleaseConfirmView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Please confirm")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But hmm sounds crazy that we HAVE to use two navigation links..? I just want the equivalence of ONE single `UIButton`, being disabled, until BOTH Toggles are `on`.

Comment: Problem is that turning isActive to off does not hide a priorly-shown details view, so a replacement must go active to hide it. You can use a conditional to show a different view once both got enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are misunderstanding the meaning of the `NavigationLink` init you are using.

```
/// Creates an instance that presents `destination` when active, with a
/// `Text` label generated from a title string.
public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, destination: Destination, isActive: Binding<Bool>)
```

That `isActive` doesn't mean that the link is clickable only when that bool is true. That means that you are creating a `NavigationLink` that triggers the navigation *both* on click *and when* the `isActive` binding becomes true.

You can achieve what you want with the `disabled` modifier this way:

```
struct WelcomeScene: View {
    @State var hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions: Bool = false
    @State var hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                Spacer()

                Toggle(isOn: $hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions) {
                    Text("I agree to the Terms and Conditions")
                }.toggleStyle(DefaultToggleStyle())

                Toggle(isOn: $hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy) {
                    Text("I agree to the Privacy Policy")
                }.toggleStyle(DefaultToggleStyle())

                NavigationLink("Proceed", destination: SignInScene())
                    .disabled(!hasAgreedToTermsAndConditions || !hasAgreedToPrivacyPolicy)
            }.padding(30)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the `enabled`/`disabled` state of the `NavigationLink` get updated when any of the Toggles `isOn` changes?

Comment: @Sajjon Yes, sure. You can try yourself copy-pasting the code in my answer. When one of the toggles changes the view gets recreated since one of its State property has changed. And then the disabled bool is recomputed.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm unable to try the solution out :(, every time I toggle the switch I see this following text message in the console: `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.`

Comment: @Sajjon If you copy-paste my code and you get that error it's really strange (I can run it without any issue). It must be a bug related to xCode Beta. Sometimes I can get rid of its silly bugs closing xCode, deleting the DerivedData folder (xCode->Preferences->Locations) and open xCode again.

Comment: @Sajjon You can even try the solution without running on the simulator, but using the Live Preview (this way you shouldn't see the error you see on the simulator).

Comment: deleting derived data was the first thing I tried of course :). I have restarted Xcode, my computer, I have deleted the simulator... same thing every time. In a comment above I referenced to this SO Q, might be the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56980875/1311272

Comment: @Sajjon did you try with the Live Preview? (without actually using the simulator)

Comment: Live preview does not update the NavigationLink either. Not even if using a Single Toggle (reducing complexity of the view, seems like `State` is broken. I've tried with `EnvironmentObject` (user data) and `Publisher`, does not work either, same error being logged

Comment: The message appears here too, but it doesn't crash anything and it doesn't stop the Toggle from working. So go try out time :)

Comment: I also see error `[WindowServer] display_timer_callback: unexpected state (now:17cce5d70d7 < expected:17ccf558677)` every time I press a toggle. But hmm seems like my `@State` properties does not work at all. Something is completely broken. bah! I might reinstall Xcode 11 (beta 5).

Comment: @Sajjon are you on Catalina Beta 5? Cause other versions of Catalina don’t support SwiftUI Beta 5.

Comment: @superpuccio yes Catalina beta 5 (19A526h)

Comment: that second message show up for everyone too. But that should not influence any @State variables. It is just about a timer callback in the background somewhere..

Comment: @superpuccio it was a red herring, I updated the question, I actually used `disabled` prior to posting my question, so my code was correct all the time, just because of `invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes'` error, the `Toggle`s never worked so I could not try it. Just tried on device, works fine!