# Inability to debug SwitfUI Views with print

Tags: swift, swiftui

This simple code that I want to observe the `body` calculation doesn't work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isOn = false
    var body: some View {
        print("MainView body")
        
        return Toggle("Toggle", isOn: $isOn)
    }
}
```

When I toggle the `Toggle` I'm getting errors:

On iOS:

```
[5502:364282] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
```

On macOS:

```
[5522:365624] Metal API Validation Enabled
[5522:365624] Unable to locate MetalPluginName property or is of the wrong type
[5522:365624] +[MTLIOAccelDevice registerDevices]: Zero Metal services found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980875/what-does-invalid-mode-kcfrunloopcommonmodes-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' ..."mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980875/what-does-invalid-mode-kcfrunloopcommonmodes-mean)